# Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on a non-object in /blah/blah/blah.php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

I am trying to use prepared statements in msyql queries to prevent SQL Injections.

I have replaced the line:

```
$this->Query_ID = @mysql_query($Query_String_Clean,$this->Link_ID);
```

With this:

```
$preparedQuery  = $this->Link_ID->prepare($Query_String_Clean);
$this->Query_ID = $preparedQuery->execute();
```

But its not working, giving the error:

```
Call to a member function execute() on a non-object
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Did you initialized `$this->Link_ID`

Comment: @User016: No. I didn't.

Comment: It means ->prepare did not return an object instance as expected but  false due to an error. Check `mysqli_stmt::$error` http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.error.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you read with MySQLi:

Take a look into this one:

```
<?php
// Init the database connection
$db = new mysqli("example.com", "user", "password", "database");

// Look for errors or throw an exception
if ($db->connect_errno) {
    throw new Exception($db->connect_error, $db->connect_errno);
}

// Init prepared statement
$prep = $db->stmt_init();

// Prepared statement
$prep = $db->prepare("SELECT username, points FROM account_information WHERE username = ? AND username IS NOT NULL AND username != ''");

// See if statement is ok
if (!$prep) {
    throw new Exception($db->error);
}

// Put your variables into the query
$prep->bind_param('s', $_SESSION['username']);

// Fire the query!
$prep->execute();

// This is magic, it's awesome.. try it :-))
$prep->bind_result($username, $points);

// Get the results easily
while ($prep->fetch()) {
    echo "{$username} has {$points}<br>", PHP_EOL;
}

// This is like in our house, when we leave it, we close the door
$prep->close();
$db->close();
```